# How to execute two Cucumber test runners sequentially

Tags: selenium, cucumber, bdd

We are using Cucumber + Selenium framework.
I have implemented the rerun plugin which captures the failed cases.
Now to execute those failed ones I need to have one extra test runner where I can pass the failed cases path which was created using first test runners execution.

Here I want the solution where I can run both these test runners sequentially so that the entire suite gets executed in one and any failed scripts are got executed in the second runner.

Test Runner1:-

```
@RunWith(ExtendedCucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(format = { "json:target/cucumber.json", "pretty" }, features = ".", 
glue = {"" }, tags = { "@TestSuite" }, plugin = {"rerun:target/rerun.txt" })
```

Test Runner2:-

```
@RunWith(ExtendedCucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(format = { "json:target/cucumber.json","pretty" },features = "@target/rerun.txt",glue = {"" },plugin = {"rerun:target/rerun.txt" })
```

I want to execute only one instance and it should execute both above but Test Runner 1 and Test Runner 2 sequentially as Test Runner 2 has input dependency.

Comment: If both runners are in the same folder level, name them in alphabetically increasing order so the rerun comes second.